# When i am try to run the test cases using jest in react native then i am getting this issue

Tags: react-native, ts-jest, react-navigation-stack

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'navigator')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHhM.png)

// include this line for mocking react-native-gesture-handler
import 'react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup';

// include this section and the NativeAnimatedHelper section for mocking react-native-reanimated
jest.mock('react-native-reanimated', () => {
const Reanimated = require('react-native-reanimated/mock');

// The mock for `call` immediately calls the callback which is incorrect
// So we override it with a no-op
Reanimated.default.call = () => {};

return Reanimated;
});

// Silence the warning: Animated: `useNativeDriver` is not supported because the native animated module is missing
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Animated/NativeAnimatedHelper');

I had created the one file for the set up and that file path set in package json file but, still this issue was not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't imported jest in setup file then try importing like below

```
import {jest} from '@jest/globals';
```